# Flow Control with C++

Tags: c++

I known my question would be very not clever question , but I just would like to know your suggestion

I would like to have method as below

```
void ClassABC::someMethod(){

    // portion 1
    .
    .
    .
    return ;

   // portion 2 
   .
   .
   .
   .
   return;

   // portion 3
   .
   .
   .
   . 
   return;
}
```

portion 1 will run when call someMethod() at  first time .

portion 2 will run when call someMethod() at  second time .

portion 3 will run when call someMethod() at  third time and .

I know I can have global variable/private object's variable to check which portion to run , but just want to hear from you too ! ,
you can apply with "goto" statement as well ,

Thank you & Best Regrads.
Puwanat S.

Comment: "...run when call someMethod() at first time" - first time for the object instance, or the first time for the class?  i.e. is you have `ClassABC a, c; a.someMethod(); b.someMethod();` - should `b.someMethod();` run portion 1 or 2?

Comment: @Tony D ,first time of object instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void ClassABC::someMethod() {
    static size_t counter = 0;

    switch (counter++) {
        case 0: {
            // 1
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            // 2
            break;
        }
        default: {
            // 3
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this approach would only work for a `static` member function.

For non-static member functions use this:

```
class ClassABC {
public:
    ClassABC();
    void someMethod();
private:
    size_t someMethodCounter;
}

ClassABC::ClassABC() {
    this->someMethodCounter = 0;
}

void ClassABC::someMethod() {
    switch (this->someMethodCounter++) {
    // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In embedded systems, we would use a function pointer.  It typically has lower overhead than a switch statement, especially if one case is going to run repeatedly.

```
void ClassABC
{
  void part1() {
    // portion 1 ;
    op_= part2 ;
  }
  void part2() {
    // portion 2
    op_= part3 ;
  void part3() {
    // portion 3
  }

  void someMethod() { op_() ; }

  std::function<void()> op_ = part1 ;
} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what makes the most sense.  You could also do

```
void ClassABC::someMethod1() { ... }
void ClassABC::someMethod2() { ... }
void ClassABC::someMethod3() { ... }
```

Instead, though the caller(s) would have to be slightly more aware of their context.

Or, it could do

```
int  ClassABC::someMethodIndex;
void ClassABC::someMethod()
{
    switch (someMethodIndex)
    {
    case 0:   ... // first portion
              someMethodIndex = 1;  // next time do portion 1
              return;
    case 1:   ... // second portion
              someMethodIndex = 2;  // next time do portion 2
              return;
    case 2:   ... // third portion
              someMethodIndex = 0;  // next time do portion 0
              return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you count for all object of the class, you can use static data members: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1b5y48f.aspx

It's much better from the encapsulation point of view than a global variable.

If you count for every object of the class separately then just use a regular private member variable that will store the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable and a `switch` statement:

```
switch(counter++) {
case 0:
    // portion 1
    break;
case 1:
    // portion 2
    break;
case 2:
    // portion 3
    break;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a static variable inside the method initialized to zero, and increment on every call and make a decision to call the appropriate portion of the code.